# How to recover Jupyter Notebook file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, recovery

I was working on a jupyter notebook since two days on Brave browser. It was supposed to be saved but It did not. I ran file several times, so its updated version is executed successfully. But after I updated browser and relaunch it, the file has gone. Now I have the version two days ago. Is there any way to recover the last executed file from cache or somewhere else. I found some files in browser's cache folder but I am afraid they are also former versions. It seems, only two days ago it saved a checkpoint and after that it crashed and did not update again.

Comment: Depend on the cache setting of your web browser, cache should contain your last edited jupyter notebook. Suggest you duplicate cache files with date of your last use of the notebook, and use a text editor to inspect and locate your notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to recover my deleted .ipynb file.

The cache is in `~/.cache/chromium/Default/Cache/` (I use chromium)
used grep in binary search mode, `grep -a 'import math'` (replace search string by a keyword specific in your code)

Edit the binary file in vim (it doesn't open in gedit)
The python ipynb should file start with '{ "cells":' and
ends with '"nbformat": 4, "nbformat_minor": 2}'
remove everything outside these start and end points
Rename the file as .ipynb, open it in your jupyter-notebook, it works.

---

I think the easiest way (until developers handle this issue) to retrieve your Ipython history is to write them all into an empty file.

You need to check by the date you created your last script. Obviously, it is going to be the last part of your Ipython history.

To write your Ipython history into a file:

`%history -g -f anyfilename`

---

Alternatively (I haven't tested this):

You could:

1. Open the Local History view.
2. Select the version you want to roll back to.
3. On the context menu of the selection, choose Revert.

Answer (score 0):

If you've saved notebook and checkpoint using save symbol instead of relying on auto-saving, you could revert back to latest checkpoint by selecting file>revert to checkpoint.